# Minimize window event for MAC OS X in objective c

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am not able to get any event when mac os x application is minimized to dock. Although there are notifications fired when your application becomes active and inactive but no such event for minimizing windows.

```
if(hasUserNotification)
{
    //Notification delivered code here....
}
```

If condition should be executed only when the mac application is in inactive state or minimized state otherwise in foreground no notification should be shown.

Comment: Share your code/workaround first

Comment: Windows are minimized, applications are hidden.

Answer (score -1):

i think i can use applicationDidChangeOcclusionState notification in AppDelegate class. This gets called everytime when you mnimize your application to the dock and maximize also.

```
- (void)applicationDidChangeOcclusionState:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([NSApp occlusionState] & NSApplicationOcclusionStateVisible) {
        // The app is visible; continue doing work
        NSLog(@"app is visible");
    } else {
        // The app is not visible; stop doing work }
        NSLog(@"app is not visible");
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, edit your question.